# is it possible to close JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(buttonPanel," ") with timer?if it's possible pls tell me how(the program code is down)

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*; // Graphics import java.awt.Color; // Graphics Colors 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; // Events 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; // Events

public class ButtonDemo_Extended implements ActionListener {

    // Definition of global values and items that are part of the GUI.
    int redScoreAmount = 0;
    int blueScoreAmount = 0;

    JPanel titlePanel, scorePanel, buttonPanel;
    JLabel redLabel, blueLabel, redScore, blueScore;
    JButton redButton, blueButton, resetButton;

    public JPanel createContentPane() {

        // We create a bottom JPanel to place everything on.
        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();
        totalGUI.setLayout(null);

        // Creation of a Panel to contain the title labels
        titlePanel = new JPanel();
        titlePanel.setLayout(null);
        titlePanel.setLocation(10, 10);
        titlePanel.setSize(250, 30);
        totalGUI.add(titlePanel);

        redLabel = new JLabel("Red Team");
        redLabel.setLocation(0, 0);
        redLabel.setSize(120, 30);
        redLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        redLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
        titlePanel.add(redLabel);

        blueLabel = new JLabel("Blue Team");
        blueLabel.setLocation(130, 0);
        blueLabel.setSize(120, 30);
        blueLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        blueLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        titlePanel.add(blueLabel);

        // Creation of a Panel to contain the score labels.
        scorePanel = new JPanel();
        scorePanel.setLayout(null);
        scorePanel.setLocation(10, 40);
        scorePanel.setSize(260, 30);
        totalGUI.add(scorePanel);

        redScore = new JLabel("" + redScoreAmount);
        redScore.setLocation(0, 0);
        redScore.setSize(120, 30);
        redScore.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        scorePanel.add(redScore);

        blueScore = new JLabel("" + blueScoreAmount);
        blueScore.setLocation(130, 0);
        blueScore.setSize(120, 30);
        blueScore.setHorizontalAlignment(0);
        scorePanel.add(blueScore);

        // Creation of a Panel to contain all the JButtons.
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(null);
        buttonPanel.setLocation(10, 80);
        buttonPanel.setSize(260, 70);
        totalGUI.add(buttonPanel);

        // We create a button and manipulate it using the syntax we have
        // used before. Now each button has an ActionListener which posts 
        // its action out when the button is pressed.
        redButton = new JButton("Red Score!");
        redButton.setLocation(0, 0);
        redButton.setSize(120, 30);
        redButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(redButton);

        blueButton = new JButton("Blue Score!");
        blueButton.setLocation(130, 0);
        blueButton.setSize(120, 30);
        blueButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(blueButton);

        resetButton = new JButton("Reset Score");
        resetButton.setLocation(0, 40);
        resetButton.setSize(250, 30);
        resetButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(resetButton);
        return totalGUI;
    }

    // This is the new ActionPerformed Method.
    // It catches any events with an ActionListener attached.
    // Using an if statement, we can determine which button was pressed
    // and change the appropriate values in our GUI.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == redButton) {
            redScoreAmount = redScoreAmount + 1;
            redScore.setText("" + redScoreAmount);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(buttonPanel, "GOOOOOOOOOOOL");
        } else if (e.getSource() == blueButton) {
            blueScoreAmount = blueScoreAmount + 1;
            blueScore.setText("" + blueScoreAmount);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(buttonPanel, "GOOOOOOOOOOOL");
        } else if (e.getSource() == resetButton) {
            redScoreAmount = 0;
            blueScoreAmount = 0;
            redScore.setText("" + redScoreAmount);
            blueScore.setText("" + blueScoreAmount);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() { // For this Class Onlyyyyyyyyyyyy .

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true); // Style Of Frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] JButton Scores! [=]");

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        ButtonDemo_Extended demo = new ButtonDemo_Extended();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(280, 190);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        createAndShowGUI();

    } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might be one way to do it:

`

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AutoCloseJOption {

private static final int TIME_VISIBLE = 3000;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("My App");
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setSize(100, 100);
    frame1.setLocation(100, 100);

    JButton button = new JButton("My Button");
    frame1.getContentPane().add(button);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "Title");
            dialog.setModal(false);
            dialog.setVisible(true);

            new Timer(TIME_VISIBLE, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    dialog.setVisible(false);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });

    frame1.setVisible(true);

  }
}`
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: thank you alot of helping one more thing i know its dumb but im not good on java    how to use this code u gave me on the project exactly /? i make it on another class on the packge and then link it ? and how to link it :/ ik its too much asking but i hope you help me more

Comment: yw, as you said you want show a message in JoptionPane with a timer to show it in specific seconds or minutes .. so you need a timer to do this (new Timer .. new ActionListener) after timer starts, in 3 second your code will be run (dialog will hide) for more info go read about event handling topic in java.